# mongodb org.springframework.data.authentication.UserCredentials No default constructor found

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I just started to use mongodb as repository of my new project, Every thing was ok until we decided to set user authentication in mongo server.

I change my spring.config.xml as below to connect to mongo with authentication

```
<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongo" ref="mongo"/>
    <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="admin"/>
    <constructor-arg name="userCredentials" ref="mongoCredentials"/>
</bean>

<bean id="mongoCredentials" class="org.springframework.data.authentication.UserCredentials">
    <property name="username" value="user" />
    <property name="password" value="password" />
</bean>

<bean class="com.mongodb.MongoURI" id="mongoURI">
    <constructor-arg value="mongodb://localhost:27017"  />
</bean>

<bean class="com.mongodb.Mongo" id="mongo">
    <constructor-arg ref="mongoURI" />
</bean>
```

and this is stack trace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [spring-config.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoCredentials' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoCredentials' defined in class path resource [spring-config.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.authentication.UserCredentials]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.data.authentication.UserCredentials.<init>()
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:648)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:140)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
at com.tosan.test.Test.main(Test.java:27)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoCredentials' defined in class path resource [spring-config.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.authentication.UserCredentials]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.data.authentication.UserCredentials.<init>()
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1105)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1050)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
... 17 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.authentication.UserCredentials]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.data.authentication.UserCredentials.<init>()
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:85)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1098)
... 25 more
 Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.data.authentication.UserCredentials.<init>()
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:80)
... 26 more
```

part of pom.xml:

```
    <properties>
    <spring.version>4.2.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.icu</groupId>
        <artifactId>icu4j</artifactId>
        <version>57.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

I appreciate your help.

Comment: At a glance you appear to be copying config from an older post on this site. I suggest you [actually do what the manual says instead.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/current/reference/html/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**UserCredentials**](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/authentication/UserCredentials.html) class does not have a default construct, it has one with following arguments: `UserCredentials(String username, String password)`. You have to modify your bean definition to use this constructor:

```
<bean id="mongoCredentials" class="org.springframework.data.authentication.UserCredentials">
    <constructor-arg value="user"  />
    <constructor-arg value="password"  />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<bean id="mongoCredentials" class="org.springframework.data.authentication.UserCredentials">
<constructor-arg value="user"></constructor-arg>
<constructor-arg value="password"></constructor-arg>
```

The way you have configured it, Spring attempts to call the default constructor and then call the setters. But of course there is no default constructor, so Spring reports the exception